# How do I get the second last record of a table in laravel

Tags: laravel, record, css-tables

I want the second last record from my table and search already and 
I tried this:

```
$news2 = News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get();
```

but nothing works.

I get this error:

> Property [datum] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\j4ylara\resources\views\user\start.blade.php)

If I want the last one everything works it perfectly.

```
$news1 = News::all()->last();
```

and my view is the same

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 news">


    <div class="news-content">
                    <div class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> {{ $news1->datum }}</div>
                    <h4 class="news-title">{{ $news1->newstitel }}</h4>
                    <p class="news-text">{{ $news1->newsbeschreibung }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                        mehr lesen &raquo;
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters news-wrapper">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 news-image">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/385/370/?random">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 news">
                <div class="news-content">
                    <div class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>{{ $news2->datum }}</div>
                    <h4 class="news-title">{{ $news2->newstitel }}</h4>
                    <p class="news-text">{{ $news2->newsbeschreibung }}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                        mehr lesen &raquo;
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: where you call `var datum`

Comment: `get` returns a collection **always**. you don't have a single model, you have a collection object

Comment: you need one result or more? on `news2`

Comment: only one row and i want the title , the date and the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GET IIIIIIIIIIIT AHHHHHHHHHH :)

```
$row = News::count();
        $newsid = $row -2;
        $news1 = News::all()->last();
        $news2 = News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip($newsid)->take($newsid)->first();
        return view('user/start', compact('news1', 'news2', 'newsid'));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$news2 = News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->first();
```

this return only one `result` if you need more you need used `foreach` inside `blade`

Comment: it shows me the second row but i want the second last row, so if i have 4 rows i want to show row 3 and if i have 5 rows i want to show row 4 ...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is from the view, you are probably calling to a "datum" property for an object and one of them does not exist:

```
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\j4ylara\resources\views\user\start.blade.php)
```

The query looks good to me

Comment: <div class="news-content">
                            <div class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> {{ $news2->datum }}</div>
                            <h4 class="news-title">{{ $news2->newstitel }}</h4>
                            <p class="news-text">{{ $news2->newsbeschreibung }}</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                                mehr lesen &raquo;
                            </a>


this is my view

Comment: Try @dd($news) in your view to see what's returning

Comment: Collection {#629 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶]
} this

Comment: but idk what this mean

Comment: I think I may know what the error is, you're returning a collection and you need one object, get returns a collection, try adding first() at the end of your query and run it again as: $news2 = News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get()->first();

Comment: ah okay thank you it works but now i have the last one and not the second last?

Comment: Try: $news2 = News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(2)->get()[1];

Comment: This is a collection, an array of news: $news2 = News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(2)->get(); already ordered to what you need, you can pass it to the view and there you can call the position you want, instead of saying news2->datum, you can say news2[1]->datum;

Comment: it shows me the second row but i want the second last row, so if i have 4 rows i want to show row 3 and if i have 5 rows i want to show row 4 ...

Comment: Change the order_by to "ASC"

Answer (score 0):

try to use `getModel()` instead of `get()` to get query result

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$news2 = News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->offset(1)->take(1)->first();
```

`get()` returns collection of News. You must use `first()`

Comment: it shows me the second row but i want the second last row, so if i have 4 rows i want to show row 3 and if i have 5 rows i want to show row 4 ...